# Como fazer os componentes visuais do Delphi 2010 seguirem o padrão visual do Windows?

Tags: delphi, windows, look-and-feel

No Delphi 2010 os componentes de interface (botões, etc) são todos quadrados, estilo Windows 95/98.

Como faço ele adaptar o padrão visual as versões mais recentes do Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ir em Project -> Options -> Application e selecionar a opção "Enable runtime themes".

Uma outra opção é usar um componente TXPManifest, que faz com que ele sempre tenha o visual do windows XP. Vc só precisa colocar ele em 1 form da aplicação e, depois de carregado ele ativa a funcionalidade para todos os formulários.